# Не меняется цвет кнопки в bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Пытаюсь изменить background кнопки с классом .btn-brand, но ничего не происходит.

Код navbar`a:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white sticky-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="images\landing\mainIcon.svg"/>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto"> 
        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-nav"> 
        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AboutUs">Contact Information</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-brand">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Код css:

```
/* BTN */
.btn {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.btn-brand {
    color:white;
    background-color: #6970dd;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользовательский css следует подключать лишь после bootstrap css.